# Understanding issue with Error Handling in a for loop VBA

Tags: vba, for-loop, error-handling

I wrote some examples to highlight what my issue in understanding is.

**1. Example:** This works as expected. The error is getting handled via the `Goto` Statement and the error handling is returned to normal behavior arfterwards

```
Sub ErrorHandlingWithoutLoop()
    Debug.Print "Before Error"
    On Error GoTo errorHandler
    
    Error (1)
    
    ' If no Error occured, the ErrorHandling procedure is skipped
    GoTo skip
    
errorHandler:
    Debug.Print "Handle Error"
    On Error GoTo 0
    
skip:
    Debug.Print "After Error"
    
    'Raise Error to see if error Handling is resumed to normal behavior
    Error (14)
End Sub
```

VBA returns:

```
Before Error
Handle Error
After Error
```

And the Error Handling is returned to normal, visible by the thrown error (14)

**Example 2:** I would expect this sub to run through just fine and just throw an error in the last line with error (14).
However in the second loop with n=2, the error handling doesnt work as intended. Why?

```
Sub ErrorHandlingWithLoop()
    Debug.Print "Before Error"

    For n = 1 To 10
        On Error GoTo errorHandler
        Error (1)
        
        ' If no Error occured, the ErrorHandling procedure is skipped
        GoTo skip
errorHandler:
        Debug.Print "Handle Error", n
        On Error GoTo 0
skip:
        Debug.Print "After Error", n
    Next n
    
    'Raise Error to see if error Handling is resumed to normal behavior
    ' -> This wont be reached though
    Error (14)
End Sub
```

VBA returns:

```
Before Error
Handle Error   1 
After Error    1
```

The execution of the code stops in the second loop with n=2 with a thrown error of 1. The Error 14 at the end is not thrown

**Example 3:** I know I can fix this behaviour by adding a "resume skip" statement. **However I dont understand why this is necessary?**

```
Sub ErrorHandlingWithLoopFixed()
    Debug.Print "Before Error"

    For n = 1 To 10
        On Error GoTo errorHandler
        Error (1)
        
        ' If no Error occured, the ErrorHandling procedure is skipped
        GoTo skip
errorHandler:
        Debug.Print "Handle Error", n
        On Error GoTo 0
        Resume skip
skip:
        Debug.Print "After Error", n
    Next n
    
    'Raise Error to confirm that error Handling is resumed to normal behavior
    Error (14)
End Sub
```

VBA returns:

```
Before Error
Handle Error   1 
After Error    1 
Handle Error   2 
After Error    2 
Handle Error   3 
After Error    3 
Handle Error   4 
After Error    4 
Handle Error   5 
After Error    5 
Handle Error   6 
After Error    6 
Handle Error   7 
After Error    7 
Handle Error   8 
After Error    8 
Handle Error   9 
After Error    9 
Handle Error   10 
After Error    10
```

And the Error Handling is returned to normal, visible by the thrown error (14)

**So why is the *Resume skip*  necessary?!**
Thanks for any help=)

Edit:
***!Bonus Example!3:*** Interestingly, if I add a `On Error Goto -1`, then the for-loop loops infinitely. Why is that? I cant make a rhyme of that...

```
Sub ErrorHandlingWithLoop()
    Debug.Print "Before Error"

    For n = 1 To 10
        On Error GoTo errorHandler
        Error (1)
        
        ' If no Error occured, the ErrorHandling procedure is skipped
        GoTo skip
errorHandler:
        Debug.Print "Handle Error", n
        On Error GoTo -1
skip:
        Debug.Print "After Error", n
    Next n
    
    'Raise Error to see if error Handling is resumed to normal behavior
    ' -> This wont be reached though
    Error (14)
End Sub
```

VBA returns:

```
Before Error
Handle Error   1 
After Error    1 
Handle Error   2 
After Error    2 
Handle Error   3 
After Error    3 
Handle Error   4 
After Error    4 
Handle Error   5 
After Error    5 
Handle Error   6 
After Error    6 
Handle Error   7 
After Error    7 
Handle Error   8 
...
...
...
```

This continues on and on until Excel crashes.
**Any help on this as well?**

Comment: You probably should not be calling `On Error Goto...` inside your error handler - generally from there you only use `Resume...` And it's more typical to place the error handler blocks at the end of the method, with an `Exit Sub|Function` above them so normal execution doesn't run into them.  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ErrorHandling.htm is a good overview

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would not follow the example you provide to deal with error handling.  Instead I would encapsulate the action that might result in an error in its own function which returns true or false depending on whether or not the action was successful or not.  The value returned by the action is passed out of the function using a ByRef parameter.

```
Sub ErrorHandlingWithLoopFixed()
    Debug.Print "Before Error"

    Dim myResult as Variant
    For n = 1 To 10

        If Not TryAction( myResult) then
        
            Debug.Print "An error occurred"
            Stop ' or exit function or whatever
        end if
        
        ' Continue processing myResult

    Next n
    
    'Raise Error to confirm that error Handling is resumed to normal behavior
    Error (14)
End Sub

Public Function TryAction( ByRef opResult) as Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    opResult = ' the action
    TryAction = err.number = 0
    On Error Goto 0

Exit Function
```

As you can see from above, the code is much easier to follow and there are no problems with jumping in and out of the scope of a For loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is indeed nice to know some best practices. However your answer doesnt help me understand WHY the resume is needed or WHY On Error Goto -1 causes the loop to loop infinately.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

For example 2: the reason you need Resume skip is that an error handler only "handles" once and gets deactivated. After that you must activate it again which is exactly what resume does.

[Paul Kelly](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/) names this: "reseting the mouse trap", because like a mouse trap an error handler gets deactivated when used, and you need to activate it manually for it to work again.
All these can perform that task (activate the mouse trap): resume label, resume next, on error goto -1. Also On Error Resume Next takes care of the reactivation itself (you don't need to do it manually for that one).

For the bonus the reason for the infinite loop is that you have an error right befor the end, but no Exit Sub before it. So whenever you reach that error you'll be thrown back in the error handler, which you've put in the loop. A safer way is to have your error handlers at the end, after an exit sub.